# How add a link to the CSS file contained in the dll assembled by Costura to a Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, fody, fody-costura

Here is a project where everything has already been added, all that remains is to run it and see the problem. Style is not applied to `<h1 class="title">Hello, world!</h1>`
[linkToProject](https://github.com/agile11tiger/Blazor)

The nuget package I'm using [costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura)
[Which path should I use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cDXL.jpg)

[bundle properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPhGa.jpg)
[ilSpy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdIvG.jpg)
Don't add a link to the project directly, I know it will work, but I need it to work through the dll that Costura compiled.
Expected result: the style will be applied.
[Expected result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Buvdi.jpg)